# How to position an image such that its bottom coincides with the vertical center of a layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-imageview

I tried adding an image to a layout through an ImageView and setting the layout gravity of the ImageView to be `center_vertical`. But this places the center of the image at the vertical center of the layout. Instead, I want the bottom of the image to be at the vertical center of the layout. Is this possible?

Thank you all for helping out yet again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using a RelativeLayout, what you can do is create a 1dp by 1dp View (lets call it spacer_view) and center it vertically to the parent.

Then you can take your ImageView and "align_bottom" with the spacer_view.

```
<View
   android:id="@+id/spacer_view"
   android:layout_width="1dp"
   android:layout_height="1dp"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/my_image"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spacer_view" />
```

Comment: Nice idea! I was planning on using a FrameLayout - any tweaks possible there?

Comment: Unless you absolutely HAVE to use a FrameLayout, I would recommend just using RelativeLayouts. I almost exclusively use them and have never had any issues. I just find you have a lot more flexibility with them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer Tajonny07 gave will be the best and easiest way to do it in my opinion.
This can't be done with a FrameLayout as you suggested though. That is because `android:layout_centerHorizontal` and `android:layout_centerVertical` are invalid parameters in a FrameLayout. A RelativeLayout does a fine job most of the time, depending on what you are making. Is a FrameLayout
 required in the application you are making?

Comment: Thanks! I agree that RelativeLayout seems to be the way to go. I am working with Fragments, so had been using FrameLayouts until now. You can set gravity to be center_vertical and center_horizontal with FrameLayouts though.

Comment: That is true, although `layout_alignBottom` is also not available when using a FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```